# Personalized service printing

Tags: delphi, vcl

Good morning,

My problem is that I have a main program that calls a service (created by me, too) that it does is create some files subsequently sent to the print queue in Windows, the problem is when this program is executed by a windows 8 taking all permits and to run as administrator does not work, or prints or anything and gives the following error "no currently no default printer selected" (error completely random because if there default printer selected).

The service operation is simple, select the printer that there stored in the database and if this printer is the same as Windows sends the generated file in windows 7, xp, vista and other operating systems prior to Windows 8 functions perfectly.

Onsite windows 8 is 64 bits.

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

I have already solved, I passed the source code to a normal program (without being a windows service) and it works perfectly.